# Where clause in R while joining dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I am new to R programming. I have a task to join the dataframes using where condition filer. I have 2 data frames below I would like to join df2$B_col2 to df1 by col1 but only if df1$A_col2=1.

I used below code it gives the result but I know the code is efficient. If there is any way to drop the records while joining the tables itself, please let me know.

```
Df1      col1      A_col2
1          b          1
2          a          1
3          a          0
4          c          0
5          d          1

Df2      col1      B_col2
1          a          10                     
2          b          20
3          c          30
4          d          40
5          e          50
```

code

```
df3 <- left_join(df1,df2, by = "col1")
df4 <- df3[df3$df1col2 == 1,]
```

Output

```
 col1 df1col2 df2col2
1    b       1      20
2    a       1      10
5    d       1      40
```

Comment: `left_join(df1[df1$A_col2 == 1,], df2, by = "col1")`?

Comment: Hi Roland, Yes this is what exactly I am looking for. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you ware with base R, you can try `merge` + `subset` like below

```
> subset(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), A_col2 > 0)
  col1 A_col2 B_col2
1    a      1     10
3    b      1     20
5    d      1     40
```

or `match` + `subset`

```
> subset(
+   transform(
+     df1,
+     B_col2 = df2$B_col2[match(col1, df2$col1)]
+   ),
+   A_col2 > 0
+ )
  col1 A_col2 B_col2
1    b      1     20
2    a      1     10
5    d      1     40
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on = .(col1)][A_col2 > 0]
   col1 B_col2 A_col2
1:    b     20      1
2:    a     10      1
3:    d     40      1
```